# Crashing NumberPicker, changed keyboard type

Tags: android

My android app keeps chrashing when I change the keyboard type on my numberPicker to "TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER", when typing the first digit. The same works without specifying the keyboard type. So it seems that the keyboard change is the problem.
Here's the code:

```
public void chooseAmps(View view) {
    final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
    NumberPicker.Formatter formatter = new PickerFormatter();
    //numberPicker.setFormatter(formatter);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(100);
    numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(getStringArray(0, 10));
    enableNumberPickerManualEditing(numberPicker);


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.AmpsMessage)
            .setTitle(R.string.AmpsTitle)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("UI", String.valueOf(numberPicker.getValue()));
                    double currentDesired = numberPicker.getValue() / 10.0;
                    charger.setCurrentDesired(currentDesired);
                    Log.d("UI", String.valueOf(charger.getCurrentDesired()));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            })
            .setView(numberPicker);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

String[] getStringArray(double begin, double end) {
    String[] stringArray = new String[(int) ((end - begin) * 10)+1];
    double number = begin;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) ((end - begin) * 10+1); i++) {
        stringArray[i] = String.format("%.1f", number);
        number += 0.1;
    }
    Log.d("UI", String.valueOf(number));
    return stringArray;
}

public static void enableNumberPickerManualEditing(NumberPicker numPicker) {
    int childCount = numPicker.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View childView = numPicker.getChildAt(i);

        if (childView instanceof EditText) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) childView;
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}

The crash message here:

> "Process: com.jacobi.mario.charger, PID: 28169
>                                                                            java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (3 ... 3) ends beyond
>   length 2
>                                                                                 at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1320)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:683)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:676)
>                                                                                 at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:78)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:96)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.widget.NumberPicker$SetSelectionCommand.run(NumberPicker.java:2278)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)"

Anybody got a tip for me?

Answer (score 0):

Wow I just found a solution, but maybe there is a better on?

For me it worked to change:
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
to
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

Comment: had the same problem. Will try this solution but it'll take time because I have to wait if crash-reports vanish...

Comment: At least on Android 11 this change causes a different behavior of the number input keyboard. It allows many other characters, even line feeds, so it's not suitable for me.